# PHP: data is not in the same charset

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

So i've struggled with this for a while and didn't manage to find the solution.

My problem is that i'm generating CSV from API and it has some Croatian signs in it. It went well and I used this function to generate CSV file

```
function generateCSV($arr, $option) {
   if ($option == 'Products') {
        $fp = fopen('csv/products.csv', 'w');

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            fputcsv($fp, $value, ";");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occured when i had to extract the data from a CSV file on a different server and include it into equation. I think the encoding of that file messed things up.

My CSV looks sth like this

reference | name | random columns..... | description

The description part is the one which i'm including from the other CSV file from a different server. Part of code in which i'm saving it to a file is here:

```
function generateDescriptionCSV(){
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.---.hr/---/--/Proizvodi.csv');
    $fp = fopen('csv/products_descriptions.csv', 'w');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

So i have to sources of data. One is the API provided calls to database and the second one is this file i generate using CURL. When i glue those data together the data from API is displayed fine while the data from external CSV looks ok except for the croatian signs which are very important in this case.

When I try to open final CSV file in Excel using UTF-8 encoding i get something like this.

> 05-120000 Mozaik plo**č**a sa dodacima, 23x17,5x4,8 c 59.99   64  KREATIVNI
>   SETOVI,PRIBOR ZA IZRADU   Spol:Ž  set za slaganje mozaik slika, set se
>   sastoji od plo?e za nabadanje 16x21 cm, 192 komada nabadalica raznih
>   boja i oblika, te posudice koja zajedno s plo?om ?ini kofer?i? za
>   spremanje nabadalica (18x23x4 cm)

Question marks should be displayed exactly the same as the character above and that is **č**

When i open both final CSV file and the external on in Notepad and then try to 'save as' them to find the encoding of the files for the first file I get UTF-8 and for the second one ANSI

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I tried calling outputting encoding via `mb_detect_encoding` and this is what i came up with

http://shorttext.com/7a59c8f1

First line is the data from the API source and the second line is the data from External CSV. When i'm opening that external CSV with Excel using From Text import File origin is checked as 1250: Central European (Windows) and when i change that to UTF-8 every special sign is presented as this symbol �.
When i try to open the final - generated CSV file File origin is checked as 8592: Central European (ISO) special signs coming from api are presented normally while the signs coming from that external CSV are presented as �.

Maybe that helps in pointing where the problem lies

Comment: Well... how is the data encoded that you're writing to the CSV? Where does it come from?

Comment: Dont know if I understand your question? The first set of data is from API which is connected to a local database and the second set of data is from that external CSV. Is there a way to check the encoding of the data inside PHP?

Comment: Maybe start with [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and/or [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: I've just added a little bit more info to my question and hadn't got the time to read the whole article but will surely do it when i get home.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally resolved my problem using this function `iconv('windows-1250','UTF-8', $data[33]);` to change encoding of strings to UTF-8